# Access Extern IP behind NAT

Tags: cisco, nat, ip

I have found many articles, possible solutions to this topic, but no one seems to have the same problem as me. I am working on a Cisco 1812 Router with IOS 12.4. I have found some things like hairpinning and DNS doctoring but those methods doesn't sound the right one, because every solution targets on the problem that you can't access it over its domainname.

We have 2 extern ip addresses x.x.x.100 and x.x.x.101 which get nated to the inside addresses i.i.i.100 and i.i.i.101.

so x.x.x.100 -> i.i.i.100

and x.x.x.101 -> i.i.i.101

My Configuration:

```
ip nat inside source route-map SDM_RMAP_1 interface FastEthernet0 overload
    ip nat inside source static i.i.i.100 x.x.x.100 route-map SDM_NAT_TEST
    ip nat inside source static i.i.i.101 x.x.x.101 route-map DM_RMAP_1

interface FastEthernet0
 description Interface Outside
 ip address <external IP> 255.255.255.240
 ip access-group Internet in
 ip nat outside
 ip inspect firewall out
 ip virtual-reassembly
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1452
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 crypto map vpn
 service-policy output CLEAR-TOS
!         
interface FastEthernet1
 description Interface Inside
 ip address 172.16.18.1 255.255.255.0
 ip flow ingress
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no keepalive
! 
interface FastEthernet2
    description DMZ
     ip address i.i.i.i 255.255.255.0
     ip access-group DMZ_IN in
     no ip unreachables
     ip flow ingress
     ip nat inside
     ip inspect firewall out
     ip virtual-reassembly
```

In Interface FE2 are the Webserver which get natted. FE0 is my outgoing Interface to my Provider. And FE1 is my Internal Network where every client connects to.

I have no problem to reach to Webserver in the DMZ from the Inside Interface with his i.i.i.100 - IP. But i can't access him with his external IP x.x.x.100. You can reach him when you are on the Outside of my network (like you try to connect with your phone).

Funny thing is, i can ping his External IP but if i want to navigate in Firefox to this IP the connection will get refused.

There isn't a problem with the DNS, because I want to reach him with his IP. If i navigate to his internal IP, no Problem.

I need to fix this, because if you connect to an VPN you can't access it anymore, because the DNS from the VPN will connect you to the external IP. This was the first time a recognized this behavoir.

BIG EDIT: **I didn't configure this router**, it was someone else which isn't reachable anymore. So I have to figure everything out which is done on this one.

Comment: Have few time for now but war you're looking for IS actually NAT hairpinning. Have a look [here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12102421/nat-hairpinning) for an example.

Comment: Hi, I also find this thread, but i don't get it. I found a solution on ASA, which I understand, but not this one. On the ASA he added a second NAT rule:
static (inside, inside)  i.i.i.i x.x.x.x netmask 255.255.255.255. Which i understand is doing forwarding public IP x.x.x.x to inside interface with IP i.i.i.i ? Or am i wrong?

I found it [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/71704-dns-doctoring-2zones.html#solution2)

Comment: @SystemCookie, the solution you describe is NAT hairpin routing. It translates the public destination IP address to a local IP address. Routing should then send the packet to the new, local destination. This is a pretty inefficient way to accomplish this since you want to use the DNS name. The best way is to configure your DNS server to handle it correctly for you so that you get the internal address internally, but you get the public address when you try to reach it from outside. There are questions and answers about how to do that on [sf]. The configuration of DNS servers is off-topic here.

Comment: @RonMaupin Actually you can reach the Server on the inside with his inside IP. And on the outside, with his public. But if a employee has VPN to another network, the DNS of this extern network (example custimer) delievers to external IP address of the Server and you get connection refused (because you are actually on the inside interface). And there is the Problem, all the employees have to put the DNS Server manually into their network config if they have VPN activated. Is this understandable? Because i'm from Austria (german lang.)

Comment: Hairpin routing should work for that, but you may be able to come up with a better solution for the PCs, which would be off-topic here. You could try on [sf] or [su] for that. Your English seems fine. I had four years of German in high school, aber es hat ein zehr langes Zeit gewesen. Don't judge me too harshly on that since it has been nearly 40 years. :)

Comment: You really googled a lot about hairpinning. But i don't get this to work. I will also look for other solutions, at the moment the employees are manipulating their /etc/resolv.conf or the /etc/hosts file. On Windows they turn off VPN, go on the internal mail-server, turn on VPN. It is 40years ago, when you went to school? Damn, thats two times longer as i'm alive (i'm 20). Btw. German is really really hard to learn.
We soon change to ASA, i read that i can do DNS-doctoring there. So i think it will be an easier task to do this on ASA.